# Can you write rules in a programmatic if-then style?

Tags: spamassassin

Can you do if-then style statements in SpamAssassin?

I get spam sent to me that uses my email address for the sender's name and I would like to write a general rule for this.

For example, I receive spam messages with From: and To: lines like this:

```
From: "me@mydomain.org" <spam@spam.com>
To: <me@mydomain.org>
```

Below I refer to this format as:

```
From: "Name" <address>
To: <address>
```

Is it possible to write a rule that says:

```
if 
  the (From: name)
  is equal to (To: email address)
  but not the (From: email address)
then 
 give it a score?
```

I am thinking this specifically in case my server automatically sends messages in a similar format, such as: `"root@mydomain.org" <root@mydomain.org>`.
I don't want the rule to accidentally score emails like that.

I only see how to write positive rules.  So I can look for these kinds of simple matches

```
header LOCAL_FROM_NAME_MyAddress   From =~ /\"me@mydomain.org\"/

header LOCAL_FROM_Address_MyAddress   From =~ /<me@mydomain.org>/

header LOCAL_TO_Address_MyAddress   From =~ /<me@mydomain.org>/
```

So I could create a score if they all produced a match:

```
meta LOCAL_FROM_ME_TO_ME ((LOCAL_FROM_NAME_MyAddress + LOCAL_FROM_Address_MyAddress + LOCAL_TO_Address_MyAddress) >2)
score LOCAL_FROM_ME_TO_ME -0.1
```

But that is as far as I can go.  I haven't seen any way to do something more complex.

Answer (score 1):

SpamAssassin `meta` rules support boolean expressions, so you can use the `&&`, `||`, and `!`  operators to create more complex matches. In the specific example you've given, the rule is logically equivalent to:

```
(FROM_NAME equals MyAddress) and (FROM_ADDR does not equal MyAddress)
```

A ruleset to express this could be:

```
header __LOCAL_FROM_NAME_MyAddress  From:name =~ /me\@mydomain\.org/
header __LOCAL_FROM_ADDR_MyAddress  From:addr =~ /me\@mydomain\.org/
meta LOCAL_SPOOFED_FROM (__LOCAL_FROM_NAME_MyAddress && !__LOCAL_FROM_ADDR_MyAddress)
score LOCAL_SPOOFED_FROM 5.0
```

If meta rules and boolean expressions are not enough, you can write a Perl plugin. Check out the many [examples on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/dist/Mail-SpamAssassin), and perhaps specifically [Mail::SpamAssassin:FromMailSpoof](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::FromNameSpoof).

###### Notes

- You can write `:name` and `:addr` to parse specific parts of the `From` and `To` headers.
- You can prefix your sub-rules with `__` so that they will not score on their own.
- Special characters like `@` and `.` should be escaped in regex patterns.